# Why is the "free store" memory called the "heap"?

Tags: ds.data-structures, ho.history-overview

Does it have anything to do with the heap data structure, for example the [Buddy blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) implementation, or does it only take the literal English meaning of the word (a big pile)?

I know heap memory is more practical than theoretical, but there's no Stack Exchange for "Practical Computer Science" yet.

Comment: This might be of your interest http://stackoverflow.com/q/1699057/58737

Comment: Me bad, this a dup of a dup. I didn't search on SO at all. Someone please close this as such.

Comment: The answer is available as linked in these comments. Since this really isn't about "theoretical computer science," I'll simply close it as [off topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with the data structure.
It's just the opposite of the **stack**, which carefully orders its elements and doesn't allow them to be read or written except at the top.

Comment: That's where the confusion comes in. The stack memory is exactly a stack data structure, whereas the heap memory has nothing to do with heap ds.